# Probability of all boxes containing a ball when distributing n balls into k boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Based on [This link](http://math.mit.edu/~rothvoss/18.304.3PM/Presentations/1-Shawn-Combinatorics101.pdf) from MIT, the number of distributions of n identical balls into k boxes where no box is empty is 
${n-1 \choose k-1}$ and The total number of distributions of n identical balls into k boxes is ${n+k-1 \choose k-1}$.

Therefore, shouldn't the probability $P$ of a random distribution having no boxes empty be given by

$P = {n-1 \choose k-1} / {n+k-1 \choose k-1}$

I tried this with the example $k = 10, P = .5$ and ended up with $n = 129$. After running some computer simulations of distributing 129 balls into 10 boxes it seems there is a much greater than 50% chance of having no empty boxes. Where is my mistake?

Comment: **Hint:** Although "stars and bars" counts *distinct* events, it does *not* count *equally probable* outcomes.  Do *not* use it for probability calculations.

Comment: Elaborating on what @GrahamKemp said, there is only one way your simulation could put all $129$ balls in the first box, but there are very many ways your simulation could put, say, $65$ balls in box $1$ and $64$ balls in box $2$ (although that is still quite unlikely). In your calculation, you consider these outcomes equally likely, but they are not equally likely outcomes of a simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple example: Two Ball, Two Boxes.

Outcomes by "stars and bars" ( indistinct balls , distinct boxes): $\boxed{**|~~}, \boxed{~*|*~}, \boxed{~~|**}$

That is $\dbinom{2+2-1}{2-1}$ distinct events, $\dbinom{2-1}{2-1}$ of which have no boxes empty.

However, not all of these events are equally probable.   Though the balls aren't distinguishable by an observer, they actually are distinct objects.   We could write numbers on them with invisible ink, for instance.   The middle event can then be seen to be satisfied in two different ways.

Outcomes by using "secretly-distinct" balls: $\boxed{12~\mid ~~~},\boxed{~1\mid 2~}, \boxed{~2\mid 1~}, \boxed{~~~\mid~12} $.  That is: $2^2$ equally probable outcomes, $2^2-\binom 2 1\cdot 1^2$ of which have no empty boxes (by P.I.E.).

Can you extend this to higher cases (using the principle of inclusion and exclusion)?