# Classical Probability of buckets and balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If we have $n$ bucket and $\beta$ balls and each ball is thrown to a bucket randomly, then what is the probability of "Every bucket at least has a ball in it"?

I tried 2 ways:

1. I try to calculate from the inverse, and then I can give the probability of bucket $i$ has at least one ball
   $$p_i=1-\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^\beta,$$ but they seem not independent that I can't just multiply them up;
2. I try to calculate the number of samples that $\beta$ balls cover $m$ buckets, but I can't see the pattern in it.

Where should I go?

Thank you.

Comment: @DavidK thanks I was making the same mistake described here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1712367/probability-of-all-boxes-containing-a-ball-when-distributing-n-balls-into-k-boxe

Comment: @3rdMoment You're welcome. I figured you'd know what I meant.

Comment: The answer of $$1 - \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \left(n - k\right)^\beta}{n^\beta}$$ can be manually derived by a study of Inclusion Exclusion.  See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for an 
introduction to Inclusion-Exclusion.
Then, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427605/inclusion-exclusion-principle-what-is-1n1/4427645#4427645) for an explanation of and justification for the Inclusion-Exclusion *formula*.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot everyone!